# fetch records in specific order but keep some specific records in always top mysql

Tags: mysql

I have one DB table called `table1` have some columns two of them are

```
purchased enum ('Y','N') default 'N';
created timestamp ;
```

I want to fetch records newest on top but the records with `purchased 'Y'` will always be on very top and these records should also be sorted in newest to oldest.

How do I do query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY purchased DESC, created DESC
```